# Is that possible to make recursive functions in 10.2.31-MariaDB-log? If not what are the alternatives?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/ it says that RECURSIVE keyword was added in MariaDB 10.2.0

That's mentioned here too:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-102/

When I look for version data it says my version is 10.2.31.

But I can't use RECURSIVE keyword in my PhpMyAdmin. Why it's not avialable?

**Is that possible to make recursive functions in 10.2.31-MariaDB-log? If not what are the alternatives?**

Here's some data about the server I use:

```
version:  10.2.31-MariaDB-log

innodb_version:  5.7.29

protocol_version:  10

slave_type_conversions:  

version:  10.2.31-MariaDB-log

version_comment:   MariaDB Server

version_compile_machine:  x86_64

version_compile_os:  Linux

version_malloc_library:  system

version_ssl_library:   OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

wsrep_patch_version:   wsrep_25.24
```

Comment: what syntax are you trying? `RECURSIVE` is for CTEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-function-limitations/ says:

> - Cannot be used recursively.

The `RECURSIVE` keyword is for use with [recursive common table expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/).